# How do I go about obtaining the origin of a point via an instance variable?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor

I'm fairly new to C++ and one of my first assignments in my current class has a focus on us trying to understand headers, implementations, pointers, constructors, and the like. This particular assignment has us working with x and y coordinates. I've gotten most of this completed, but I'm not quite sure what I've done so far is going to work and there are a few parts I've completely stuck on; I haven't even been able to test this yet. Also, I apologize in advance if I'm not using the proper terminology for some of this.

There are two headers, and here is an abstract one (Point.h) that doesn't require me to edit it, but is important as a reference to the entire assignment:

```
using length_unit = double;
using coordinate_unit = double;

/**
 * A Point Interface.
 */
class Point {
public:
    /**
     * Calculate the distance this Point is from the origin.
     * @return The distance this Point is from the origin is returned.
     */
    virtual length_unit DistanceFromOrigin() const = 0;

    /**
     * Calculate the distance this Point is from the given Point.
     * @param other another Point in the plane
     * @return The distance this Point is from the given Point is returned.
     */
    virtual length_unit DistanceFromPoint(const Point &other) const = 0;

    virtual ~Point() = default;
};
```

Here's another header (TwoDimensionalPoint.h) that I was only required to add private data members with the stipulation that they have to pointers:

```
#include "Point.h"

/**
 * An implementation of the Point interface in a two-dimensional plane.
 */
class TwoDimensionalPoint : public Point {
private:
    // TODO: Add appropriate data members
    coordinate_unit *x_coordinate;
    coordinate_unit *y_coordinate;

public:
    /**
     * Default/initializing constructor.
     * @param x_coordinate the x-coordinate of this Point
     * @param y_coordinate the y-coordinate of this Point
     */
    explicit TwoDimensionalPoint(coordinate_unit x_coordinate = 0, coordinate_unit y_coordinate = 0);

    /* The Big Five */

    /**
     * Destructor responsible for deleting memory occupied by the coordinates of this Point.
     */
    ~TwoDimensionalPoint() override;

    /**
     * Copy constructor used to create a new Point with the same coordinates of the other Point.
     * @param other a Point used as a template for creating this point using copy semantics
     */
    TwoDimensionalPoint(const TwoDimensionalPoint &other);

    /**
     * Move constructor used to create a new Point with the same coordinates of the other Point.
     * @param other a Point used as a template for creating this point using move semantics
     */
    TwoDimensionalPoint(TwoDimensionalPoint &&other) noexcept;

    /**
     * Copy assignment operator used to create a new Point with the same coordinates as the other Point.
     * @param rhs an l-value; the right-hand side of the assignment statement lhs = rhs
     * @return A new Point with the same coordinates as the given (l-value) TwoDimensionalPoint is returned.
     */
    TwoDimensionalPoint &operator=(const TwoDimensionalPoint &rhs);

    /**
     * Move assignment operator used to create a new Point with the same coordinates as the other Point.
     * @param rhs an r-value; the right-hand side of the assignment statement TwoDimensionalPoint lhs = TwoDimensionalPoint{x, y}
     * @return A new Point with the same coordinates as the given (r-value) TwoDimensional Point is returned.
     */
    TwoDimensionalPoint &operator=(TwoDimensionalPoint &&rhs);

    /* Inherited Point behavior */

    /**
     * @copydoc Point::DistanceFromOrigin() const
     */
    length_unit DistanceFromOrigin() const override;

    /**
     * @copydoc Point::DistanceFromPoint(const Point &other) const
     */
    length_unit DistanceFromPoint(const Point &other) const override;

    /* Specific TwoDimensionalPoint behavior */

    /**
     * X-coordinate accessor method.
     * @return The x-coordinate of this Point is returned.
     */
    virtual length_unit GetX() const;

    /**
     * Y-coordinate accessor method.
     * @return The y-coordinate of this Point is returned.
     */
    virtual length_unit GetY() const;

    /**
     * Assess whether this Point is the origin.
     * @return True if this Point is the origin, otherwise false.
     */
    virtual bool IsOrigin() const;

    /**
     * Translates this Point by the given dimensions.
     * @param x the amount to translate in the x-direction
     * @param y the amount to translate in the y-direction
     */
    void Translate(coordinate_unit x = 0, coordinate_unit y = 0);
};
```

And then finally the implementation (TwoDimensionalPoint.cpp) is the meat and potatoes of what I need to do; I have to complete the areas with commented with "TODO":

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include "TwoDimensionalPoint.h"

TwoDimensionalPoint::TwoDimensionalPoint(coordinate_unit x_coordinate, coordinate_unit y_coordinate) {
    // TODO: Add an appropriate initializer list
    x_coordinate = new coordinate_unit{ x_coordinate };
    y_coordinate = new coordinate_unit{ y_coordinate };
}

TwoDimensionalPoint::~TwoDimensionalPoint() {
    // TODO: Delete appropriate data members
    delete x_coordinate, y_coordinate; 
}

TwoDimensionalPoint::TwoDimensionalPoint(const TwoDimensionalPoint &other) {
    // TODO: Add an appropriate initializer list
    x_coordinate = new coordinate_unit{ *other.x_coordinate };
    y_coordinate = new coordinate_unit{ *other.y_coordinate };
}

TwoDimensionalPoint::TwoDimensionalPoint(TwoDimensionalPoint &&other) noexcept {
    // TODO: Add an appropriate initializer list and appropriate body
    other.x_coordinate = nullptr;
    other.y_coordinate = nullptr;
}

TwoDimensionalPoint &TwoDimensionalPoint::operator=(const TwoDimensionalPoint &rhs) {
    // TODO: Add any appropriate code
    if (this != &rhs)
        *x_coordinate = *rhs.x_coordinate;
        *y_coordinate = *rhs.y_coordinate;
    return *this;
}

TwoDimensionalPoint &TwoDimensionalPoint::operator=(TwoDimensionalPoint &&rhs) {
    // TODO: Add any appropriate code
    std::swap(x_coordinate, rhs.x_coordinate);
    std::swap(y_coordinate, rhs.y_coordinate);
    return *this;
}

length_unit TwoDimensionalPoint::DistanceFromOrigin() const {
    // TODO: Calculate and return the correct value
    const coordinate_unit temp_x = 0 - //no idea
    const coordinate_unit temp_y =  0 - //no idea
    return sqrt( pow(temp_x, 2) + pow(temp_x, 2) ); 
}

length_unit TwoDimensionalPoint::DistanceFromPoint(const Point &other) const {
    // TODO: Calculate and return the correct value
    const coordinate_unit x_diff = other.GetX() - GetX();
    const coordinate_unit y_diff = other.GetY() - GetY();
    return sqrt( pow(x_diff, 2) + pow(y_diff, 2) );
}

length_unit TwoDimensionalPoint::GetX() const {
    // TODO: Return the appropriate value
    const coordinate_unit *x_coordinate = &x_coordinate;
    return *x_coordinate;
}

length_unit TwoDimensionalPoint::GetY() const {
    // TODO: Return the appropriate value
    const coordinate_unit *y_coordinate = &y_coordinate;
    return *y_coordinate;
}

bool TwoDimensionalPoint::IsOrigin() const {
    // TODO Return the correct value
    if //unfinished due to not knowing how to complete DistanceFromOrigin()

    else
    return false;
}

void TwoDimensionalPoint::Translate(coordinate_unit x, coordinate_unit y) {
    // TODO: Implement me
    std::cout << "X is translated by: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Y is translated by: " << y << std::endl;
} //This part confuses me as well since there are different parameters. I.e., x and y instead of x_coordinate and y_coordinate like throughout the rest of the program.
```

I feel like I'm close to finishing this, but Visual Studio Code has been throwing some problems throughout this, so I'm not completely certain. I've added some of my own comments to point out areas I'm particularly stuck. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you store the member variables with pointers and then create instances by `new` in constructor? That doesn't make sense. Use instead `coordinate_unit x_coordinate, y_coordinate;` and drop all this `new` and `delete` stuff. It's unnecessary overhead in your design.

Comment: It's amusing how a simple `struct Point { double x, y; };` is expanded to so much code ...

Comment: This assignment can not be solved in a proper way. The simple reason is that it's broken by design: The `Point` baseclass has a `DistanceFromPoint()` function that takes another `Point`. However, it doesn't provide any accessors for its coordinates. It can't, because derived classes could have any number of dimensions (not just two) who's axis' are labeled any way (not just X and Y). In order to compute the distance, you need a point in the same vector space though.

Comment: You are overthinking this. A point is the origin if and only if all its coordinates are zero – you don't need to calculate anything. Once you consider this, calculating the distance from the origin also becomes easier.

Comment: You need to look up what an initializer list is. Also, read the chapter about pointers a few more times and do all previous exercises. Read about the syntax of conditionals  (`if`). (You are not close to finishing this – most of your functions have at least one issue.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I do think this was intentionally designed to be overly complex so we have to think through it and use the concepts we're learning. Needless to say, I've been a bit overwhelmed by it and no wonder I got a few errors! I do imagine this is "solvable," since I don't think my professor would assign it as homework otherwise, albeit in a convoluted fashion. I do agree I need to keep studying initializer lists and pointers though. The `if` syntax I'm aware of, but I just left that as is for now. Any other comments are appreciated as I work through this!

Comment: @Zavage Distance can be expressed as a point if origo is [0,0...0] right? A vector of sorts? Does that trigger anything?